# Error: "Failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest" when building a Docker image

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-image, docker-desktop, docker-build

I get the error:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest

when building the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8
COPY . /inetpub/wwwroot
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The cause was simple. I had my Docker desktop running on Linux containers and the image was build from a Windows image.

Simply switching to Windows containers solved the problem.

The message is clueless, so I hope this save some time for others.

Comment: I work on Windows WSL and i have an error like "failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse platform : "" is an invalid component of "": platform specifier component must match "^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$": invalid argument", can you give more details plz

Comment: For whoever is wondering, to switch from Linux to Windows containers you just have to right click on the Docker icon in your _system tray icons_ -- assuming you're in Windows -- and then click on "Switch to Windows containers..."

Comment: @RaphaelSetin As I have understood so far, it is possible for Docker desktop on Windows , can it be done also on Docker for Mac?

Comment: @HomaPourMohammadi this is not possible in a MacOS, but there are workarounds which involve more work, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650721/can-i-run-windows-containers-on-docker-desktop-for-mac/68908748#68908748).

Comment: For some reason, the "Switch to Windows containers..." option wasn't visible, so I ran a `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCLI.exe -SwitchDaemon` command instead as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67007851/2047725)

Comment: Also you might have to enable windows containers using: Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All

Answer (score 87):

Providing the platform in the Docker file on [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) fixed it for me.

E.g., `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 amazonlinux:2018.03`

Comment: This worked for me!, I'm running this image on a mac M1  and i had to update the Dockerfile to this `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 maven:3.6-jdk-8-slim`

Comment: Worked here too. Im using M1 Monterey with amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk image

Comment: The native platform appears to be linux/arm64/v8, so if your container can use it, you can use `FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 ...`

Comment: I'm on windows and this worked for me. I was having the following error : 
`failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:37bfa5a2240dcd178564aa9ee041ae2c88dde18c662c2c7ddc965e26724a81bb: not found`
With a docker file of one line : `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2022`. I transformed it to this `FROM --platform=windows/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2022` and I was able to build (At least start donwload)

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 48):

In my case, I was using a Mac with an [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) processor to run a Python image. My **docker-compose** and **Dockerfile** looked like this:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  words_bot:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3-onbuild
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ["python", "-m", "bot"]
```

It seems like the image was expecting an **x86** host architecture, so I was getting the error the OP is referring to.

After I added **platform: linux/amd64** into **docker-compose.yml** everything started working as expected:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  cng_words_bot:
    build: .
    platform: linux/amd64
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: Awesome, You save my day!

Comment: However this breaks the setup for a Linux environment. Would be nice to have a solution that could work everywhere 

Comment: @Jonny I haven't run into this problem on linux because my mac and linux server are both arm, if you want to use python on both architectures you can try a different (not onbuild) python image, or just build a python image yourself from ubuntu, here's an example (note: if you don't need all the ubuntu software then use alpine image of linux)


FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev pip
VOLUME /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "-m", "bot"]

Answer (score 9):

Docker gets confused with some architectures like the ARM architecture([M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) for instance). Make sure to specify the architecture (platform).

```
  services:
      service-name:
        platform: linux/x86_64. # Specify the architecture here
        image: some-image
```

Update:

> If you're using an Apple Silicon Chip machine (arm architecture), you shall
> activate on you Docker Desktop the following features for better virtualization:
>
> - `Use Virtualization framework`
> - `Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon`

It will use the `Rosetta 2` emulator instead of the `qemu` one,
The difference is just outstanding.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the Docker image itself was not building. So I had to add `--platform linux/x86_64` as parameter for `docker build` command.

Answer (score 4):

(Assuming you are running Docker on a Windows platform) To resolve this issue, switch the container from Linux to Windows by right clicking on the Docker icon in the tray (we see this icon near the system clock after starting the Docker Engine) and select the option **"Switch to Windows containers..."**

**Step 1**

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**

[image: Step 2]

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled over a similar issue myself when using Docker build on a very simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

COPY ./ /app/
RUN cd /app && npm ci && npm run build
```

When running `docker build -t foo .`, the OP's error with a slightly different cause came up.

However, when running `docker pull node:lts-alpine` first, then repeating that build command, the build was running just fine.

IMHO, this looks like a hiccup in Docker for Windows. Switching to Windows containers didn't seem like a reasonable option here for the base container is pretty valid for a Linux-based context. I tried to switch anyway, but that was bringing up a different error of Docker for Windows, only.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS with an Intel chip, building a "standard" Docker image, I ran into this.

Restarting the Docker daemon fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I was using a Mac [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1), and it was missing a `/`, like the following:

How it was:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  service-name:
    build:
      # It was without the /, like:
      context: .
```

Fixed:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  service-name:
    build:
      # The correct one
      context: ./
```

The error was:

```
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: unexpected status code [manifests latest]: 401 Unauthorized
```

And also I needed to change the credsStore value. More information: *[docker pull gives error: no basic auth credentials #207](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/issues/207#issuecomment-733939422)*

I hope that it helps someone, I spent a lot of time to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a **Docker image tag** that works for your hardware **architecture** fixes it. For instance, if you are using [Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) ([M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) or [M2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M2)), the architecture is arm64.

[image: See image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was simply disconnected from the wifi, so double-check that you're online before spending hours trying to debug the issue!