# How can I run Go code with Bazel on Windows platform on my Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, docker, go, bazel

I have to test Go code using Bazel on Windows Platform to make sure the tests pass on Windows too. However, I have a Mac machine. I have tried VirtualBox/Vagrant setup and shared the directory. I can get Go to work there too. Bazel gives some version conflict with Visual Studio, but I have a workaround with `go test`.

Is there a known Windows image for Mac that has Golang, Bazel, etc all setup already that I can simply `docker run` or something?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an image like [`filipesilva/bazel-windows-docker-container`](https://github.com/filipesilva/bazel-windows-docker-container), made to include bazel.

You can modify its Dockerfile to include a [Golang binary archive](https://golang.org/dl/) (like [`go1.15.7.windows-amd64.zip`](https://golang.org/dl/go1.15.7.windows-amd64.zip)) you simply unzip under `%USERNAME\go`

You should end up with a Windows image, to run on your Mac [through VirtulaBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45381145/6309), or using a vagrant environment, as described in [`StefanScherer/docker-windows-box/`](https://github.com/StefanScherer/docker-windows-box/).